# Avoid decimal.TryParse to recognize "1.1.1" or "1,1,1" as decimal

Tags: c#, type-conversion, number-formatting, tryparse

I have a problem in string recognition: I'm trying to recognize a number only in correct format, but don't find how.

I'm writing a culture invariant way so I need to recognize "," and "." as decimal and thousand separator and vice-versa.

All these are correct format for me:

```
12,1
12.1
1.000,12
1,000.12
```

but things like these are wrong

```
1.2.3
1,2,3
```

I tried:

```
NumberStyles style;
decimal n;  
object valore;                                  
style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.AllowThousands;

Console.WriteLine(decimal.TryParse(valore.ToString(), style , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out n));
```

[this is the fiddle to test it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BrO7L1)

But "1,1,1" is read as valid number while "1.1.1" is not.

If I use my specific culture ("it-IT"), "1,1,1" is recognized and "1.1.1" is not.

How can I discard all not valid strings?

Comment: As far as I can tell you are not using `style` anywhere in the code

Comment: You have to know the source format provider, otherwise it's an impossible task. As you recognized yourself, both are valid under special circumstances(cultures).

Comment: @user9993, code corrected, thanks

Comment: @TimSchmelter "1.1.1" and "1,1,1" are bad, i want to discard both. what is a number with decimal separator used 2 times?

Comment: but how to distinguish "1.1.1" from "1.000.000" (or "1,1,1" from "1,000,000") without knowing the source culture?

Comment: That's not the decimal separator but the [`NumberGroupSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [`NumberGroupSizes `](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupsizes(v=vs.110).aspx) are only used for the output, leass than the maximum(default 3) is allowed.

Comment: *All these are correct format for me*.  No they are not.  You have no idea whether the value is 1000.12 or 100012.  Being off by a factor of a 100 is never very subtle.  So this just goes wrong for other strings as well, like 1,1,1.  Your assumption that you can do this correctly is just not correct.

Comment: @RenéVogt if i have 3 numbers it can be GroupSeparator but if it's only one cannot be a number. even if i decide to use only "," as separator i nedd to recognize 1,000,000 but discard 1,1,1

Comment: @HansPassant i can simply reassume question with this: i have to recognize 1,000,000 as number and 1,1,1 as string. How can i do this?

Comment: @gt.guybrush Standard .NET formatting and parsing infrastructure is not designed to handle such cases. But no matter whether you will make it work as you think you want it to, or make your own parser, you will be still stuck with one problem - ambiguity. How will you handle strings "My numbers are 1,000 1,001 1.000 1.001" (En culture) and 
"Meine Zahlen sind 1,000 1,001 1.000 1.001" (De culture)? The same string representation will mean radically different things, so it is nearly impossible to do. Some smart text analysis may recognize the language/culture, but even that will be unreliable.

Comment: You're inviting a bigger problem by allowing two number formats: what if you receive the input string "1.024"? Is that one thousand twenty four? Or one plus a fraction?

Comment: @Rik having server with EN settings and development and client pc with IT (both inalterable for many reason) causes the double language management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up this with a personal parser, i hope to find a better solution but reading comments it seems quite impossible

```
public static bool tryValoreNumerico(object valore, out decimal valoreRestituito)
    {
        decimal n;          
        string testoNormalizzato;

        valoreRestituito = 0;

        // normalizzazione
        if (valore.ToString().Contains(",") && valore.ToString().Contains("."))
        {
            if (valore.ToString().IndexOf(".") < valore.ToString().IndexOf(","))
            {
                testoNormalizzato = valore.ToString().Replace(".", "");
            }
            else
            {
                testoNormalizzato = valore.ToString().Replace(",", "");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ((valore.ToString().Length - valore.ToString().Replace(",", "").Length) > 1)
            {
                string[] pezzi = valore.ToString().Split(',');
                for (int i = 1; i < pezzi.Length; i++ )
                {
                    if (pezzi[i].Length != 3)
                        return false;
                }

                testoNormalizzato = valore.ToString().Replace(",", "");
            }
            else if ((valore.ToString().Length - valore.ToString().Replace(".", "").Length) > 1)
            {
                string[] pezzi = valore.ToString().Split('.');
                for (int i = 1; i < pezzi.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (pezzi[i].Length != 3)
                        return false;
                }

                testoNormalizzato = valore.ToString().Replace(".", "");
            }

            else
                testoNormalizzato = valore.ToString();

        }
        testoNormalizzato = testoNormalizzato.Replace(",", ".");

        if (decimal.TryParse(testoNormalizzato, out n) && testoNormalizzato == Convert.ToDecimal(testoNormalizzato, new CultureInfo("en-US")).ToString().Replace(",", "."))
        {
            valoreRestituito = Convert.ToDecimal(testoNormalizzato, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
        }
        return decimal.TryParse(testoNormalizzato, out n) && testoNormalizzato == Convert.ToDecimal(testoNormalizzato, new CultureInfo("en-US")).ToString().Replace(",", ".");

    }
```

in few words first i normalize number to EN formatand next try to convert it

last test is to see that there is no text "similar" to number because strings like "001", "100  01" are not number.

Ratio is: every string must remain inalterated: "001" converted to number become "1" that is different from original value and so this convertion must be avoided

[this is the fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lgQnEm)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `Regex` for validation and a custom parse method like this:

```
public static decimal DecimalParse(string number)
{
    if (new Regex(@"^\d+$").IsMatch(number))
    {
        return decimal.Parse(number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    if (new Regex(@"^(\d{0,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?)$").IsMatch(number))
    {
        return decimal.Parse(number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    return new Regex(@"^(\d{0,3}(\.\d{3})*(,\d+)?)$").IsMatch(number)
        ? decimal.Parse(number.Replace(".", "").Replace(",", "."), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        : 0;
}
```

Result will be:

```
string num;
num = "1,000";      Console.WriteLine("{0}", DecimalParse(num));     //1000
num = ",01";        Console.WriteLine("{0}", DecimalParse(num));     //0.01
num = ".02";        Console.WriteLine("{0}", DecimalParse(num));     //0.02
num = "12,1";       Console.WriteLine("{0}", DecimalParse(num));     //12.1
num = "12.1";       Console.WriteLine("{0}", DecimalParse(num));     //12.1
num = "1.000,12";   Console.WriteLine("{0}", DecimalParse(num));     //1000.12
num = "1.000.000,12"; Console.WriteLine("{0}", DecimalParse(num));   //1000000.12
num = "1,000.12";   Console.WriteLine("{0}", DecimalParse(num));     //1000.12
num = "1,000,000.12"; Console.WriteLine("{0}", DecimalParse(num));   //1000000.12
num = "1000";       Console.WriteLine("{0}", DecimalParse(num));     //0
num = "110.";       Console.WriteLine("{0}", DecimalParse(num));     //0
num = "110,";       Console.WriteLine("{0}", DecimalParse(num));     //0
num = "1.2.3";      Console.WriteLine("{0}", DecimalParse(num));     //0
num = "1,2,3";      Console.WriteLine("{0}", DecimalParse(num));     //0
```

Comment: cant make it work on my machine with italian culture: first regex passes but decimal.parge thow error. can you make a culture agnostic version?

Comment: Has `return decimal.Parse(number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` also error?

Comment: So, I updated my answer with using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`; and `1,2` should return `1.2` ;).

Comment: other case: 1234 is not recognized: thousand separator is not mandatory: maybe \d{0,+} instead of \d{0,3}

Comment: well if you update answer to manage number like 123456 i will accept as solution